# Not getting staking rewards on Testnet

Tags: rewards, testnet

I did staking on Testnet but have not received any rewards albeit 2 epochs passed.
Here are my two transactions made on 28th, 29th of September for which I do not see any staking information, including rewards. Would you please advise if there was some downtime on testnet / slashing etc which might be a reason of issue with rewards

```
1) 28th, September StakingAccount -> 9XTQMtB8pPjm63N4VTPzHHpGu9RfHvE8uL7J2hQiHZeN (3TWG3BtAdvPZLamGTydBL4RFfjhDPtMwxSKwJJ4FTsQkgaQVHJqGurwRD92FtHVJGkHHa9CnCjCbJKCotqHJEfhF - signature):
```

[image]

```
2) Activation Epoch - 532 (Current epoch 535)
29th, September StakingAccount  -> C7JvkDqH2xfNSMJzd6WbBQLXy8pxD2ZWtMJFz3tkXBCm
Activation Epoch - 533 (Current epoch 534)
```

For both staking, my feePayer(address)/withdrawAuthority -> DMmCYaKCz6jz1VWsQ3JndRiSqMMwniBBGCDwLZwcR4YV (no transactions at all)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the validator your stake is delegated to has been inactive for 25 days: https://solscan.io/account/A93XLdBKfc4pwEMAvdFeyxnF6HauN5erNDFbUsemWiaB?cluster=testnet

Delegate to a different validator that is active.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. Let me try with different validator

Comment: validator is active now https://solscan.io/account/A93XLdBKfc4pwEMAvdFeyxnF6HauN5erNDFbUsemWiaB?cluster=testnet

and I have no chance to get info regarding my 28/29th September transaction? I do not have TX info for DMmCYaKCz6jz1VWsQ3JndRiSqMMwniBBGCDwLZwcR4YV. I wonder if it happened to MainNet.....